# Retrive application properties from SCCM with script during a deployment

Tags: powershell, deployment, sdk, sccm

In our environment we deploy some applications with a Powershell wrapper in rare cases. For logging purposes, we want the script to retrieve properties from SCCM during installation. The properties in question are name, version and vendor. Doing some research, I figured out that I  get a instance of the CCM_Application from the SCCM 2012 Client SDK:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root\CCM\Clientsdk" -Class "CCM_Application" | Where {$_.EvaluationState -eq 12}
```

By looking for the EvaluationState value 12, I find the application in Software Center that is being currently installed. This works great for applications deployed to devices. However; when running it with applications deployed to users, it doesn't return anything. Doing some research, I discovered that CCM_Application is user centric, and the privileged service account running the script doesn't have a instance of the application.

Is there a way of making the above code work with applications deployed to users? Also; is there a better way of somehow retrieving properties from ccmexec during execution?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post.  The only way around this I know would be to create a scheduled task via group policy that runs as the logged in user.  Trigger that, have it write it to a file, and then read it.

We were doing similar work, and we were able to get what we needed by reading appenforce.log.  As crude as that is.